# margin-top of div equal to height of an other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below. I need in `$('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top' , '')`;` the margin-top to be equal to the height of ".image-in-slider". ".image-in-slider" may vary in height depending on browser window size. Can anyone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
        var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
            Div_one_top = $('.image-in-slider').offset().top,
            Div_one_height = $('.image-in-slider').outerHeight(true),
            Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        if(WindowScrollTop+Window_height >= (Div_one_top +  Div_one_height) ){

          $('#scrolloverlay').css('z-index' , '0');
          $('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top' , '');
        }else{
           $('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top' , '3000px');
          $('#scrolloverlay').css('z-index' , '0');
        }
      }).scroll();
    });
```

Comment: So why not just change the line: `$('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top' , '');` to `$('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top' , Div_one_height + 'px');` if you need that to be the height of image in slider?

Answer (score 0):

See [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle)

You should be able to do something like

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("image-in-slider");
var element = list[0]; // or use getElementById()...
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
```

Then just use the height property dynamically like you want:

```
$('#scrolloverlay').css('margin-top', height);
```